# How create sub menus using html

Tags: javascript, html

How create sub menus using html or i have to use java scripts

Comment: How to ask good questions - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but have a look on 38 drop menus using Jquery http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/